# What's the difference between di.xml in the different etc folders?

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, di

Looking at the core Magento2 modules in the vendor folder, I notice that there are `di.xml` placed in different folders `etc/adminhtml/di.xml`, `etc/frontend/di.xml` and `etc/di.xml`.

The `Magento_Cms` module itself has `di.xml` in all 3 different folders!

What's the effect of placing the `di.xml` in the 3 different folders? How can I know when I should place my `di.xml` in which folder?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Each module can have a global and area-specific `di.xml` file. Magento reads all the `di.xml` configuration files declared in the system and merges them all together by appending all nodes.

As a general rule, the area specific `di.xml` files should configure dependencies for the presentation layer, and your module’s global `di.xml` file should configure the remaining dependencies.

Magento loads The configuration in the following stages:

1. Initial (`app/etc/di.xml`)
2. Global (`<moduleDir>/etc/di.xml`)
3. Area-specific (`<moduleDir>/etc/<area>/di.xml`)

During bootstrapping, each application entry point loads the appropriate `di.xml` files for the requested area.

[SOURCE](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/extension-dev-guide/build/di-xml-file.html)

Comment: Also, plugins in area-specific di.xml are not always generated in developer mode.

Answer (score 4):

'di.xml' is used for set dependency.

You can place it in **etc** folder or **frontend** or **adminhtml** folder

but purpose to set it in different folder is :

1. **frontend** : all dependency which apply for frontend is needed to set in it, so developer can have clear idea about dependency applied for frontend development.
2. **adminhtml** : all dependency applied to admin should be placed at adminthml, so developer can identify it easily.
3. **etc** : Its for general dependency, so we can define dependency which can be used in both frontend as well as backend.

> Different folder created for different dependency can make it easy to find any dependency applied on Backend or frontend or both.